# Value of type 'Uri()' cannot be converted to 'List(Of Uri)'

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

I am in Visual Studio 2015 visual basic (which I think is what VB.net is) and getting this error:

> BC30311    Value of type 'Uri()' cannot be converted to 'List(Of Uri)'

on this line 2 of this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Pages As List(Of Uri) = {New Uri("https://google.com/")}
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Searchbar.Text.Contains("http://") Or Searchbar.Text.Contains("https://") Then
            WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri(Searchbar.Text)
            Pages.Add(New Uri(Searchbar.Text))
        Else
            If Not Searchbar.Text.Equals("") Then
                WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("http://" & Searchbar.Text)
                Pages.Add(New Uri("http://" & Searchbar.Text))
                ' Pages.Add(New Uri("http://" & Searchbar.Text))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I haven't found anything on the internet that seems to be about this specific error, and I don't see how what I am doing is different from what is on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-list-of-items). What am I doing wrong?
**Edit:** Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your code for initializing the list are wrong. See the code below.

```
Public Pages As List(Of Uri) = New List(Of Uri)(New Uri() {
        New Uri("https://google.com/"),
        New Uri("https://amazon.com/")
    })
```

Alternative code.

```
Public Pages As List(Of Uri) = New List(Of Uri) From {
        New Uri("https://google.com/"),
        New Uri("https://amazon.com/")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Han said the initialization is incorrect.  Here is another alternative

```
Public Pages As List(Of Uri) = {New Uri("https://google.com/"),
                                New Uri("http://www.vbforums.com/forumdisplay.php?25-Visual-Basic-NET/"),
                                New Uri("https://amazon.com/")}.ToList
```